# How to solve java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I'm working on a java lab and the first step is reading data from the input text file. I've been trying to fix the code but it doesn't help at all. Could you guys please take a look and let me know what I can do about it?
The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at Restaurant.<init>(Restaurant.java:35)
at RestaurantTester.main(RestaurantTester.java:11)
```

For the tester class with main method

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class RestaurantTester {
   private static Scanner buffer = new Scanner(System.in);
   private static int inputInt; 
   private static Restaurant restaurant;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      restaurant = new Restaurant();
      System.out.print("\n                 Welcome to Java Restaurant\n");
      System.out.print("\n\n*************************************\n");
      System.out.print("1. Display Menu\n");
      System.out.print("2. Display Server List\n");
      System.out.print("3. Restaurant Activities\n");
      System.out.print("4. Quit\n");
      System.out.print("*************************************\n");
      System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
      inputInt = buffer.nextInt();
      while (inputInt != 4) {
         switch (inputInt) {
            case 1: {
               restaurant.displayMenu();
               break;
            } // end case 1
            case 2: {
               restaurant.displayServerList();
               break;
            } //end case 2
            case 3:{
               System.out.print("\n\n*************************************\n");
               System.out.print("1. Restaurant Activity\n");               
               System.out.print("2. Quit\n");
               System.out.print("*************************************\n");
               System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
               inputInt = buffer.nextInt();
               while (inputInt != 2) {
                  restaurant.restaurantActivity();
                  System.out.print("\n\n*************************************\n");
                  System.out.print("1. Restaurant Activity\n");               
                  System.out.print("2. Quit\n");
                  System.out.print("*************************************\n");
                  System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
                  inputInt = buffer.nextInt();                  
               } // end inner while  
               break;
            } // end case 3 
        } // end switch
        System.out.print("\n\n*************************************\n");
        System.out.print("1. Display Menu\n");
        System.out.print("2. Display Server List\n");
        System.out.print("3. Restaurant Activities\n");
        System.out.print("4. Quit\n");
        System.out.print("*************************************\n");
        System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
        inputInt = buffer.nextInt();
      } // end outer while

      System.out.print("\nThank you. The Java restaurant is now closed.\n");
   }  // end main
    }
```

For my Restaurant class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Restaurant {
...             
  private Menu menu;
  public ArrayList<Server> servers; 
  private Activity activity;
  public Restaurant() throws FileNotFoundException {
     input = new Scanner(new File("menu.txt"));      
     menu = new Menu();
     servers = new ArrayList<Server>();

     temp = input.nextLine();  // skip 1st line             
     for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        servers.add(new Server(input.next(), (input.nextLine()).split(",",6)));             
     } // assume only 6 tables for each server  

     temp = input.nextLine(); // skip instruction line
     while (input.hasNext()) {
        str1 = input.next();    
        str2 = input.next(); 
        value = input.nextDouble();                 
        menu.setMenuItem(str1,str2, value);
     }                 
   } // end constructor 
    ....
}
```

And heres my text file:

```
Waiters: first name followed by table list
John 1,2,5,9,11,15
Maria 3,4,6,7,17,18
Mike 8,10,12,13,14,26

Menu: listing of the full menu: item code, name, price
A1 Bruschetta 5.29
A2 Caprese_Flatbread 6.10
A3 Artichoke-Spinach_Dip 3.99
A4 Lasagna_Fritta 4.99
A5 Mozzarella_Fonduta 5.99
E1 Lasagna_Classico 6.99
E2 Capellini_Pomodoro 7.99
E3 Eggplant_Parmigiana 8.99
E4 Fettuccine_Alfredo 7.49
E5 Tour_of_Italy 14.99
D1 Tiramisu 2.99
D2 Zeppoli 2.49
D3 Dolcini 3.49
S1 Soda 1.99
S2 Bella_Limonata 0.99
S3 Berry_Acqua_Fresca 2.88
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code ?

Comment: Please post your complete main method :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip one more line.

```
Skip one
read three
skip blank line?
skip instructions
loop till the end
```

From http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner-help.html:

Q: What happens if I scan a blank line with Java's Scanner?

A: It depends. If you're using nextLine(), a blank line will be read in as an empty String. This means that if you were to store the blank line in a String variable, the variable would hold "". It will NOT store " " or however many spaces were placed. If you're using next(), then it will not read blank lines at all. They are completely skipped.

My guess is that nextLine() will still trigger on a blank line, since technically the Scanner will have the empty String "". So, you could check if s.nextLine().equals("")

Comment: I tried putting another temp = input.nextLine(); after reading the first 4 lines, but then i got the nullpointerexception:

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems you need to skip two lines after finishing the first portion of the file. You skip one line, but that may just be the line space. So you need to skip again to get to your desired content. Try adding another `nextLine()`

```
input.nextline();
temp = input.nextLine();
```

---

Also, it's possible you may have a problem with the scanner not going to next line after `nextDouble()`.  If the above didn't work, Try adding a `nextLine()` after it and see if that works?

```
value = input.nextDouble();
input.nextLine();
```

Consider even using a `split` to avoid this problem

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] token = line.split("\\s+");

    str1 = tokens[0].trim();    
    str2 = tokens[1].trim();
    value = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2].trim());                 
    menu.setMenuItem(str1,str2, value);
 }
```

The above code will read each line, line by line, then split the three into an array of `String`s.  The last value will need to be parsed into a `double`.

---

**Edit: Here's another**

```
servers.add(new Server(input.next(), (input.nextLine()).split(",",6)));
```

You're reading the next, then the nextLine. You need to read all in one line

---

**Edit: try this code**

```
public Restaurant() throws FileNotFoundException {
     input = new Scanner(new File("menu.txt"));      
     menu = new Menu();
     servers = new ArrayList<Server>();

     temp = input.nextLine();  // skip 1st line             
     for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
         String line = input.nextLine();
         String[] tokens = line.split("[\\s,]+");
         String name = tokens[0];

         String[] nums = new String[6];
         for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++) {
             nums[i - 1] = tokens[i].trim();
         }
         servers.add(new Server(name, nums));             
     } // assume only 6 tables for each server  

     input.nextLine();
     temp = input.nextLine(); // skip instruction line

     while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = input.nextLine();
         String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

         str1 = tokens[0].trim();    
         str2 = tokens[1].trim();
         value = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2].trim());                 
         menu.setMenuItem(str1,str2, value);
     }                 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting error tho. It is not numberformatexception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "of"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
 at Restaurant.<init>(Restaurant.java:37)
 at RestaurantTester.main(RestaurantTester.java:11

Comment: Did you try skipping two lines like I suggested in my answer (in the beginning)?

Comment: while (input.hasNext()) {
         temp = input.nextLine();
         String[] token = temp.split("\\s");

         str1 = token[0].trim();    
         str2 = token[1].trim();
         value = Double.parseDouble(token[2].trim());                           
     menu.setMenuItem(str1,str2, value);

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe after you got a chance to look at it. I think you need to skip two lines. take a look.

Comment: I just did, I put temp = input.nextLine(); after value = Double.parseDouble(token[2].trim());. But somehow I keep getting numberformatexception again

Comment: I think it's getting a `NumberFormatException` because its trying to parse `of` from the line instruction.

Comment: No, don't put the `input.nextLine()` in the while loop. Put it above the `temp = input.nextLine()`

Comment: I just tried putting another temp = input.nextLine(); before while (input.hasNextLine()), but I got the null pointer exception.

Comment: Don't put `temp = input.nextLine()` just `input.nextLine()`. Look at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: So you have, `input.nextLine(); temp = input.nextLine();`

Comment: K. I tried input.nextLine();
      temp = input.nextLine();                        
  while (input.hasNext()) { .... And still I got the null pointer exception, I already took out the temp = input.nextLine() after value = Double.parseDouble(token[2].trim());

Comment: There are 3 lines it pointed to. One is inside this constructor: menu.setMenuItem(str1,str2, value);. The other is inside the menu class itself: menuitems.add(new MenuItem(code, name, price));. And the other is when I created the restaurant object: restaurant = new Restaurant();

Comment: I found your problem. I posted it. In your `Server` constructor, does it take a `String[]` or a `int[]` argument? That may be a problem too. On top of trying to read two lines.

Comment: Yeah its in correct format public Server(String newName, String[] table_number). One other thing, if I need to read a whole line, then how would I pass an array of token split from the input string, except for the element at 0 (which is the name?)

Comment: Thanks! But I think you missed one element by starting with i =1. Here's my code for that part:  for (int i = 0, k = 1; k < tokens.length; i++, k++) {
             nums[i] = tokens[k].trim();
         }. The thing is I still get the null pointer error pointing to not this one, but the other part that we discussed above... Sr I think I'll try working on it again in the morning.

Comment: Yeah I changed the `n[i]` to `n[i -1]` in the loop.